# How is $this->eventPrefix built?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Mangento has something that is called **dynamic events**. This are events dispatched as follows

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch($this->eventPrefix . '_load_before')
```

After what rules is the value in `$this->eventPrefix` built and who(which entity) is in charge of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$this->eventPrefix**  is a variable which  it's default value define at Abstract class like

```
Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
Magento\Framework\Data\AbstractSearchResult
Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

And it is **basically used for model class and collection class**. `$this->eventPrefix` helo to define some dynamic events base on every entity/Model.

***At Magento, most of model & collection classes are inherited from this abstract class.***

This variable override by model class.An Example like  `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\` .

**protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalog_product';**

And `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` class extends `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` by **inheritance**

So, when data load via the model class of product then fire

```
catalog_product_load_before
```

Event.

Comment: So basically for a custom entity I have to override the eventPrefix value in my model if I want to hook on the custom_entity_load_before event for example?

Comment: yes. you are right. You can override the eventPrfix for your custom entity.